# Observable.interval not working in IE

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In the angular2 application, I am using observable.interval for polling.

This is working great in Chrome. But in the IE it is not triggering Observable.interval(). When I click f12 it is immediately triggering the function. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.poll();
}
 poll(){            
        return Observable.interval(5000) 
                .switchMap(() => this.http.get('userAdmin/poll'))
                       .map(res => res.json())
                       .subscribe( 
                        data => {
                                  if(data.globalID == 'INVALID'){ 
                                 location.reload(true);
                                              }
                                   ;},
                        err => { console.log(err) ;        
                                location.reload(true);                              
                                }
                                 );
        }
```

Comment: Does it trigger only once?

Comment: You might want to create a plnkr with this behaviour and log it with the rxjs team on github.

Comment: @Alexander , yes it triggered only once. But if I go to debug mode it is triggering every 5000ms

Answer (score 0):

When using `switchMap` operator, you shouldn't subscribe yourself to the inner observable.
You should subscribe to the outer Observable, which will trigger the `interval`.

`switchMap` will then automatically subscribe to the inner Observable for you.

Comment: I am totally new to the Rxjs, can you tell me where the change has to be made